# Open File Manager shows locks that should have been released

Tags: windows, shared-storage

I have been doing some tests and I found an issue that my users experienced. My Aplliaction reads a xml file from a local network server through a DFS Path where they are granted access to. After viewing they "approve" the file a process that is part of the application moves the file to a "processed" folder. but if they open the file and the file content is fully streamed to their PC and right away they click "Approve". They get an error message saying "Can't Move file because it is either open or locked by another process. This only started happening to each user when they upgraded to Windows 7 from XP.

As a test, I created a simple console app that opens the the file, reads the file, then closes the file. On my server "SERVER A" I see the open file in the “Open File Manager” when the file closes I have press refresh for 30 sec before it was actually removed from the open file list.

This is the .net code of my test app:

```
            using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"\\oesc.ca\JEC\JustEnergy\Mississauga\Thunderhead\Review\AB_ReviewCase_120299_AB-RETENTION_SVC_26308368.xml"))
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                reader.Close();
            }
```

Does anyone know what can be causing this issue?

Comment: Funny enough I'm encountering the same issue on 2008R2...file is closed in the app but the handle stays open. Even if I close the handle I still can't delete the file until the app is closed.

Comment: Funny you should say that, This is a 2008R2 as well!